# Git reset says "Unlink of file failed. Should I try again?" but it has to be opened

Tags: windows, cmd, console-application

I made a C# console app that runs a few git commands to reset local changes. However, I get an error "Unlink of file failed. Should I try again?" because of console app is running during the process

That exe has to be run during the reset. In additionally, Git gc or git add GitDiscarder.exe did not work.

[image]

```
    internal class Program
{
    static string[] commands =
    {
        "git rm --cached -r .",
        "git reset --hard",
        "git rm .gitattributes",
        "git reset .",
        "git checkout ."
    };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++)
        {
            RunCommand(commands[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void RunCommand(string command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**** " + command + " ****");

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;

        using (Process discardProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            if (discardProcess != null)
            {
                string output = discardProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                discardProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `git add` is not enough, you need to _commit_ it too - otherwise you revert to a state where the exe doesn't exist, classic time traveling paradox :)

Comment: exe is already committed and pushed actually. Exe is not a changes while it's running @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: What you have is not a Git issue, it's a Windows issue: you want to have a command running, and at the same time, replace the file that represents the running command. That's a Windows issue. You happen to be invoking it *via* Git but it remains a Windows issue.